# django-registration, error 500 after submitting the form

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I am trying to make signup form using [django-registration](https://django-registration.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html) app. But, when I submit registration form I get message "Server Error (500)"? Please, help me - what I do wrong?

templates/registration/registration_form.html:

```
<form method="post" action="">{% csrf_token %}
    <dl class="register">
        {% for field in form %}
            <dt>{{ field.label_tag }}</dt>
            <dd class="clearfix">{{ field }}
                {% if field.help_text %}<div class="clearfix">{{ field.help_text }}</div>{% endif %}
                {% if field.errors %}<div class="myerrors clearfix">{{ field.errors }}</div>{% endif %}
            </dd>
        {% endfor %}
    </dl>
    <input type="submit" value="Register" / class="clearfix">
</form>
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
```

I ran smtp server for testing of mail sending:

```
python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025
```

There are no message with email at console

settings.py:

```
ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS = 2 #
AUTH_USER_EMAIL_UNIQUE = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
EMAIL_PORT = 1025
EMAIL_HOST_USER = ''
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'info@google.ru'

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'registration',
)
```

I created templates:

```
1.activation_email_subject.txt
Activation – {{ site }}

2.activation_email.txt
Follow {{ site }}/accounts/activate/{{ activation_key }}/

3.activate.html
Activated. <a href="{% url auth_login %}">Login</a> to site.

4.activation_email_subject.txt
Activation – {{ site }}

5.login.html
...

6.activation_complete.html
    activation_complete

7.activation_email_subject.txt
    Activation – {{ site }}

8.registration_complete.html
    Complete

9.logout.html
...
```

Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

```
/home/bo858585/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response

                            response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
    ...
▶ Local vars
/home/bo858585/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py in view
                return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
    ...
▶ Local vars
/home/bo858585/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/registration/views.py in dispatch
            return super(RegistrationView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
    ...
▶ Local vars
/home/bo858585/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py in dispatch
            return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
    ...
▶ Local vars
/home/bo858585/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/registration/views.py in post
            if form.is_valid():
    ...
▶ Local vars
/home/bo858585/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py in is_valid
            return self.is_bound and not bool(self.errors)
    ...
▶ Local vars
/home/bo858585/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py in _get_errors
                self.full_clean()
    ...
▶ Local vars
/home/bo858585/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py in full_clean
            self._clean_fields()
    ...
▶ Local vars
/home/bo858585/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py in _clean_fields
                        value = getattr(self, 'clean_%s' % name)()
    ...
▶ Local vars
/home/bo858585/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/registration/forms.py in clean_username
            existing = User.objects.filter(username__iexact=self.cleaned_data['username'])
    ...
▶ Local vars
/home/bo858585/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py in __get__
                self.model._meta.object_name, self.model._meta.swapped
    ...
▶ Local vars
```

Comment: Please post the traceback you get on the 500 error page. If you don't get a traceback, set `DEBUG=True` in your development settings

Comment: Thank you! DEBUG=True works.

Comment: AttributeError at /accounts/register/
Manager isn't available; User has been swapped for 'users.User'

Comment: It looks like you are using a custom `User` model. Please, post the code for `users.User`

Comment: Yes, I use custom. IMHO (I think so) I need to change internal code at django-registration as at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17873855/manager-isnt-available-user-has-been-swapped-for-pet-person and rebuild it from source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you swapped the default `auth.User` for a custom `users.User`.

if you want to use django-registration with a custom `User` class, you need to use a custom registration form, too. From [the source code](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/8f242e35ef7c004e035e54b4bb093c32bf77c29f/registration/forms.py?at=default):

> Note that all of these forms assume Django's bundle default `User`
>   model; since it's not possible for a form to anticipate in advance the
>   needs of custom user models, you will need to write your own forms if
>   you're using a custom model.

You need to re-implement the registration form for your custom `User` and tell django-registration to use it (set the `form_class` attribute on your registration view)

Comment: I added this 2 lines to [forms.py](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/8f242e35ef7c004e035e54b4bb093c32bf77c29f/registration/forms.py?at=default):    1. from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
   2. User = get_user_model()