# Table "auth_user" already exists, moving to custom_user model from django built it user model

Tags: django, django-migrations, django-1.9, django-custom-user, operationalerror

Question may be similar to [this situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31531606/migrate-data-from-original-user-model-to-custom-user-model-in-django-1-8) but error & version is different

I moved to [django-custom-user](https://github.com/jcugat/django-custom-user) model from Django built it user model.
Database i am using is default ie sqllite as scope of webapp is small.

After all modifications i tried to modify schema using makemigrations/migrate commands, but i am getting below error
`django.db.utils.OperationalError: table "auth_user" already exists`

As i am using Django1.9 i want to know if there is any built in option /steps to migrate data without deleting/abusing database.

```
--fake-initial      Detect if tables already exist and fake-apply initial
                    migrations if so. Make sure that the current database
                    schema matches your initial migration before using
                    this flag. Django will only check for an existing
                    table name.
```

Comment: Have you set `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'custom_user.EmailUser'` in your settings.py?

Comment: Yes I did,
`# Authentication Settings  
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts_user.EmailUser'  `

accounts_user is lable set in app.py  
`class AccountsUserConfig(AppConfig):  

    """Default configuration for custom_user."""  
    label = 'accounts_user'  
    name = 'accounts'  
    verbose_name = "Custom Email User"  `