# django 1.9 createsuperuser bypass the password validation checking

Tags: django, passwords

Try to work on the new django 1.9 version, and create a super user by this:

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

And I just want to use a simple password for my local development environment, like only one character, django1.9 upgrade to a very strict password validation policy, how can I bypass it?

```
Password: 
Password (again): 

This password is too short. It must contain at least 8 characters.

This password is too common.

This password is entirely numeric.
```

Comment: What about not using a weak password, as a habit?  Use something like [KeePass](http://keepass.info/) to generate and store and automatically type the password for you into the application?

Comment: how about give control to the users and let them decide what is the appropriate security stance? KeePass doesn't address the myriad cases where i'm not logging into a browser window.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can change the **AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS** setting in in your dev environment. See the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/passwords/#s-enabling-password-validation.

It is pretty straightforward: you will recognize the validators that caused your warning messages.

Answer (score 13):

After creating the superuser with a complex password, you can set it to something easier in the shell (./manage.py shell):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
user = User.objects.get(username='your_user')
user.set_password('simple')
user.save()
```

Comment: also you can run './manage.py shell' or 'python manage.py shell' no -- is required

Answer (score 4):

In fact, you do not need to modify the validator settings or first create a complex password and then later change it.  Instead you can create a simple password directly bypassing all password validators.

Open the django shell

`python manage.py shell`

Type:

`from django.contrib.auth.models import User`

Hit enter and then type (e.g. to use a password consisting only of the letter 'a'):

`User.objects.create_superuser('someusername', 'something@example.com', 'a')`

Hit enter again and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

**mimo**'s answer is correct but don't works if you don't using default `User` model

According **mimo**'s answer and this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17873855/manager-isnt-available-user-has-been-swapped-for-pet-person), I changed script to this one

```py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
user = User.objects.get(email='user@mail.com')
# or user = User.objects.get(username='your_user')
user.set_password('simple')
user.save()
```