# AttributeError: Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'custom_user.CustomUser'

Tags: python, django, admin, django-registration, django-custom-user

I get the error after try to solve  `User Registration with error: no such table: auth_user`
 by following [Manager isn't available; User has been swapped for 'pet.Person'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17873855/manager-isnt-available-user-has-been-swapped-for-pet-person)

i still cannot register user using my custom user registration form and i have been stuck for almost 2 weeks . im sorry if i ask a very fundamental question but i just cannot figured out why i still cant register my user . my registration page wont validate.

profiles/views.py :

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect 
from custom_user.forms import CustomUserCreationForm
from django.contrib import auth 
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
#Create your views here
def home(request):
    return render(request, "home.html")

def login(request):
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    return render(request, "login.html", c)

def about(request):
    context = locals()
    template = 'about.html'
    return render(request,template,context)

@login_required
def userProfile(request):
    user = request.user
    context = {'user': user}
    template = 'profile.html'
    return render(request,template,context)

def auth_view(request):
    username = request.POST.get['username', '']   
    password = request.POST.get['password', '']
    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user is not None:
        auth.login(request, user)
        return HTTpResponseRedirect('account/login')
    else:
        return HTTpResponseRedirect('account/login')

def register_success(request):
    return render(request, 'accounts/register_success.html')


def logout(request):
    auth.logout(request)
    return render(request, 'logout.html')

CustomUser = get_user_model()
```

register/views.py :

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from custom_user.forms import CustomUserCreationForm

#Create your views here
def register(request):
    form = UserCreationForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect ('home.html')
        else:
            return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', {'form': form})

    else:
        return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', {'form': form})

def register_success(request):
    return render(request, 'accounts/register_success.html')

CustomUser = get_user_model()
```

models.py :

```
from time import timezone
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()

class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def _create_user(self, email, password, is_staff, is_superuser, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email and password.
        """

        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email,
                          is_staff=is_staff, is_active=True,
                          is_superuser=is_superuser, last_login=now,
                           **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(email, password, False, False, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(email, password, True, True, **extra_fields)

class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username    = models.CharField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    first_name  = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True)
    second_name = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True)
    email       = models.EmailField(blank=True, unique=True)
    address1    = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True)
    address2    = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True)
    area_code   = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    country_code     = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)


    is_active    = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin     = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff     = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'address1', 'address2', 'area_code', 'country_code']

    objects = CustomUserManager()
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')

    def get_full_name(self):
        full_name = '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
        return full_name.strip()

    def get_short_name(self):
        "Returns the short name for the user."
        return self.first_name

    def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None, **kwargs):
        """
        Sends an email to this User.
        """
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email], **kwargs)
```

forms.py :

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm

class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kargs):
        super(CustomUserChangeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kargs)
        del self.fields['username']

    class Meta:
        CustomUser = get_user_model()

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kargs):
        super(CustomUserCreationForm, self).__init__( *args, **kargs)
        del self.fields['username']

    class Meta:
        CustomUser = get_user_model()

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data["username"]
        try:
            get_user_model().objects.get(username=username)
        except get_user_model().DoesNotExist:
            return username
        raise forms.ValidationError(self.error_message['duplicate_username'])
```

admin.py :

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib import admin
from custom_user.models import CustomUser

# Register your models here.
from .models import profile 

class profileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Meta:
        CustomUser = get_user_model()

admin.site.register(CustomUser)
```

the traceback :

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/register/

Django Version: 1.11.6
Python Version: 3.5.4
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'profiles',
 'contact',
 'crispy_forms',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'allauth',
 'allauth.account',
 'allauth.socialaccount',
 'checkout',
 'custom_user']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Documents\tryFOUR\src\register\views.py" in register
  12.       if form.is_valid():

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in is_valid
  183.         return self.is_bound and not self.errors

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in errors
  175.             self.full_clean()

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in full_clean
  386.         self._post_clean()

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py" in _post_clean
  413.             self.instance.full_clean(exclude=exclude, validate_unique=False)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in full_clean
  1235.             self.clean()

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py" in clean
  349.         self.email = self.__class__.objects.normalize_email(self.email)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in __get__
  198.                     cls._meta.swapped,

Exception Type: AttributeError at /accounts/register/
Exception Value: Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'custom_user.CustomUser'
```

Comment: Too much code - did the error tell you which line no?

Comment: i already upload the traceback @Mikkel

Comment: at register/views.py looks like you're using UserCreationForm instead of CustomUserCreationForm. Also you seem to have a lot of bad code. I suggest you to take a look at this example https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example

Comment: can i ask ? @if237912print in the https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example admin.py source code is stated. is it for custom_user/admin.py or admin.py?

Answer (score 1):

In views.py remove

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
```

and use CustomUserCreationForm in place of UserCreationForm in the following.