# Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'polls.User'

Tags: python, django

I have created a different version of the User model where there is no username field and I am now trying to implement a sign in feature, but I keep getting the error

```
Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'polls.User'
```

I have searched the rest of this site and tried to implement the feature beneath to fix the problem but to no avail.

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()
```

Here is the rest of my files

Views

```
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render, render_to_response, redirect
    from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
    from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
    from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

    from polls.forms import SignUpForm
    from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

    User = get_user_model()

    @login_required
    def home(request):
        return render(request, 'home.html')

    def signup(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                username = None
                raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
                user = authenticate(password=raw_password)
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('home')
        else:
            form = SignUpForm()
        return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
```

forms

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional.')
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional.')
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, help_text='Required. Inform a valid email address.')
    username = None

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', )
```

models

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, BaseUserManager
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """Define a model manager for User model with no username field."""

    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a User with the given email and password."""
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a regular User with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)


class User(AbstractUser):
    """User model."""

    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()
```

If anyone could provide any clarity on this it would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In your *forms.py* you have to also change

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

to

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()
```

This goes for everywhere you use `User`. The traceback of the error will tell you exactly where the error was caused. When seeking help debugging, always include the traceback in the question.

Comment: Thank you!!! I have found several other posts with similar solutions and no one was able to write a simple solution without paragraphs of gibberish. Thanks for keeping it simple! - This solved my problem immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Edited:
Never mind, see Håken Lid answer. I misread the problem.

But, nonetheless you have to fix the code below as well

---

Depends on what Django version you are using, but the problem is in this line:

```
user = authenticate(password=raw_password)
```

You should pass also the username:

```
user = authenticate(username='john', password='secret')
```

Then, then `authenticate` method will return either a `User` instance or `None`.

```
if user is not None:
    login(request, user)
else:
    # authenticated failed
```

Comment: Thank you, Vitor, When you are saying username='john', password='secret', I assume that translates to  username=username, password=raw_password. I apologize if this is a stupid question I'm rather new at Django

Comment: Yes, that's correct, there you would use the **username** and **raw_password**. But in your case maybe you will need to pass the email, instead of the username. Because you removed the username from the model.

Comment: This looks like the code from Practical Django 2 and Channels 2

Answer (score -2):

take a look here it been solved by others.
[solution on stackoverflow [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17873855/manager-isnt-available-user-has-been-swapped-for-pet-person)