# AttributeError: 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'accounts.Accounts'? How?

Tags: python, django, authentication, model, registration

- So I have a `Accounts` model that extends `AbstractUser` model.
- I Also have `StudentProfile` and `TeacherApplications` that have a
  one to one relation with `Accounts`.
- I ALSO have two forms for teacher and student to fill out.

**Requirement**: Enable students/teachers to register via their forms.

***Issue***: In the student/teacher form I am asking for fields that the User model needs such as `email, username, first and last name etc..` However I am getting this:.

**Error: 1**

> AttributeError at /register/ Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has
>   been swapped for 'accounts.Accounts'

**Error 2**

> ```
> Student_profile.save()
>                      ^ TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
> ```

**ISSUE: I need to register the user with user fields otherwise User fields would be null and generate error as well.. But is the best approach? Or what am I doing wrong?**

models

```
class Accounts(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField('email address', unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField('first name', max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField('last name', max_length=30, blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField('date joined', auto_now_add=True)

    # asdd
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

class StudentProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField('Accounts', related_name='student_profile')
    # additional fields for students
    AMEB_Ratings = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    is_student = models.BooleanField('student status', default=False)



class TeacherApplications(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField('Accounts', related_name='teacher_profile')
    # additional fields for teachers
    instrument = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    skill = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    experience_in_years = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField('teacher status', default=False)
```

forms

```
class StudentResistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = StudentProfile
        fields = (  
            # 'username',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'date_joined',
#           'password1',
#           'password2',
            'AMEB_Ratings',
            'is_student',

        )

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(StudentResistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        # user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        # user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.AMEB_Ratings = self.cleaned_data['AMEB_Ratings']

        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user


class TeacherRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TeacherApplications
        fields = (
            'instrument',
            'skill',
            'experience_in_years',
            'is_teacher',
        )
```

views

```
def registerStudent(request):
    # Once register page loads, either it will send to the server POST data (if the form is submitted), else if it don't send post data create a user form to register
    if request.method == "POST":
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST)
        form = StudentResistrationForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid() and user_form.is_valid():
            User = get_user_model()
            username = user_form.cleaned_data['username']
            email = user_form.cleaned_data['email']
            email = user_form.cleaned_data['password']
            new_user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, email=email, password=password)

            Student_profile = StudentProfile()
            Student_profile.user = new_user
            Student_profile.AMEB_Ratings = request.POST['AMEB_Ratings']
            # Student_profile = StudentProfile.create_user(AMEB_Ratings=AMEB_Ratings)
            new_user.save()
            Student_profile.save()
            # form.save()

            # AMEB_Ratings = form.cleaned_data['AMEB_Ratings']
            return redirect('../home/')
    else:
        #  Create the django default user form and send it as a dictionary in args to the reg_form.html page.
        user_form = UserForm()
        form = StudentResistrationForm()        

        args = {'form_student': form, 'user_form': user_form }
    return render(request, 'accounts/reg_form_students.html', args)

def teacherApplication(request):
    # # Once register page loads, either it will send to the server POST data (if the form is submitted), else if it don't send post data create a user form to register
    # if request.method == "POST":
    #   form = TeacherRegistrationForm(request.POST)
    #   if form.is_valid():
    #       instrument = form.cleaned_data['instrument']
    #       skill = form.cleaned_data['skill']
    #       experience_in_years = form.cleaned_data['experience_in_years']
    #       is_teacher = form.cleaned_data['is_teacher']
    #       form.save()
    #       return redirect('../home/')
    # else:
    #   #  Create the django default user form and send it as a dictionary in args to the reg_form.html page.
    #   user_form = UserForm()
    #   form = StudentResistrationForm()        
 #  return render(request, 'accounts/reg_form_teachers.html', {'form_student': form, 'user_form': user_form })
    pass
```

Comment: where did you get your first error? can you share us your stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change your model to something like this, I mean that `Student` and `Teacher` should inherit from account, so you dont need `is_teacher` and `is_student` anymore.

```
class StudentProfile(Accounts):
    AMEB_Ratings = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)



class TeacherApplications(Accounts):
    instrument = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    skill = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    experience_in_years = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True)
```

For your second error, I have to say the problem is indention and you should replace your `tabs` with 4 spaces.
Also I need your `urls.py` file to figure out it completely, I think problem might be there.
this link might be useful
[Manager isn't available; User has been swapped for 'pet.Person'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17873855/manager-isnt-available-user-has-been-swapped-for-pet-person?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)