# Creating Custom User Class in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication, django-users

I've read and re-read the other questions regarding this issue and I'm still unable to create a custom Django User model. I keep getting the error: `Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'Users.User'`.

If not clear by the error, I've created a `Users` app in which the `models.py` file defines a custom user class `User`.

Here's are the relevant files from my project, `UserTest`:

1. Registering the app, specifying the custom user model:

**UserTest> UserTest> settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'Users'
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'Users.User'
```

2. Extending the default Django User class via my `User` model and connecting it to a `Profile` model (not strictly relevant to the issue but a fundamental aspect of the approach.)

**UserTest > Users > models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=False, unique=True, verbose_name='Email', name='email')


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

3. Registering the new `User` model in my `Users` App's admin.py (not sure if this is required for testing quick front-end functionality?)

**UserTest > Users > admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from .models import User

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

I've created some basic forms and a view to allow front-end submission of relevant user and profile data. Given the error, I didn't feel they were relevant but I can include them if someone feels they are. Again, the error is as follows:

`Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'Users.User'`

I had initially created a custom `User` model using the `AbstractBaseUser` class, which the documentation describes states a custom Manager class must *also* be created. I had the same error using that approach and didn't read that the same customization was needed when using this approach, relying on `AbstractUser`

In my **UserTest > Users > forms.py** file, I've tried accessing my `Users.models.User` model in both of the following ways:

1. By directly importing it as such:

`from .models import User`

2. By using Django's `get_user_model()` function as such:

`from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
 User = get_user_model()`

The second approach seems to have solved this issue for many others, such as the question [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17873855/manager-isnt-available-user-has-been-swapped-for-pet-person) but doesn't help me (unless I'm missing something).

The full traceback of the error is here:

```
Internal Server Error: /test-form/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\Desktop\UserTest\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\...\Desktop\UserTest\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\...\Desktop\UserTest\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\...\Desktop\UserTest\Users\views.py", line 19, in NewUserRegistration
    print("USERFORM:", user_form, type(user_form), dir(user_form))
  File "C:\Users\...\Desktop\UserTest\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\html.py", line 397, in <lambda>
    klass.__str__ = lambda self: mark_safe(klass_str(self))
  File "C:\Users\...\Desktop\UserTest\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 142, in __str__
    return self.as_table()
  File "C:\Users\...\Desktop\UserTest\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 284, in as_table
    errors_on_separate_row=False,
  File "C:\Users\...\Desktop\UserTest\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 202, in _html_output
    top_errors = self.non_field_errors()  # Errors that should be displayed above all fields.
  File "C:\Users\...\Desktop\UserTest\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 313, in non_field_errors
    return self.errors.get(NON_FIELD_ERRORS, self.error_class(error_class='nonfield'))
  File "C:\Users\...\Desktop\UserTest\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 180, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "C:\Users\...\Desktop\UserTest\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 383, in full_clean
    self._post_clean()
  File "C:\Users\...\Desktop\UserTest\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\forms.py", line 107, in _post_clean
    super()._post_clean()
  File "C:\Users\...\Desktop\UserTest\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 403, in _post_clean
    self.instance.full_clean(exclude=exclude, validate_unique=False)
  File "C:\Users\...\Desktop\UserTest\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1137, in full_clean
    self.clean()
  File "C:\Users\...\Desktop\UserTest\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 338, in clean
    self.email = self.__class__.objects.normalize_email(self.email)
  File "C:\Users\...\Desktop\UserTest\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 188, in __get__
    cls._meta.swapped,
AttributeError: Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'Users.User'
[26/Oct/2018 09:47:02] "POST /test-form/ HTTP/1.1" 500 118088
```

I appreciate any help. Usually, if I'm able to type an entire post on SO without having an "aha" moment I know I'm pretty screwed.

**UPDATE 1: Adding `forms.py` and `views.py`**

In my `UserTest > Users` app, the `views.py` and `forms.py` are as follows:

**UserTest > Users > forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()


class NewUser(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=96)
    password = forms.PasswordInput()
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=18)

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email'].lower()
        r = User.objects.filter(email=email)
        if r.count():
            raise ValidationError("Email already exists")
        return email

    def save(self, commit=True):

        user = User.objects.create_user(
            self.cleaned_data['email'],
            self.cleaned_data['password'],
            self.cleaned_data['username']
        )
        return user
```

NOTE: Here I have tried both the `get_user_model()` approach as well as importing my custom `User` class from `Users.models` and neither resolve the error.

**UserTest > Users > views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import NewUser


def NewUserRegistration(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = NewUser(request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Account Created Successfully!')
    else:
        user_form = NewUser()

    return render(request, 'Users/test-form.html', {'user_form': user_form})
```

Comment: The traceback shows that this is happening in your NewUserRegistration view. You need to show that view and its form.

Comment: I've updated the answer, see under `Update 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the documentation explains](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-the-built-in-auth-forms), forms such as UserCreationForm" are tied to User and need to be rewritten or extended to work with a custom user model".

So, as shown there, you need to override the inner Meta class to point to your model:

```
class NewUser(UserCreationForm):
    ...
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = get_user_model()
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the issue causing the error being thrown.

Answer (score -1):

When you use custom `user model` it needs to define its `objects` i.e its `manager` which contains its various methods like `create_user` or `create_superuser`.

You can use `BaseUserManager` to inherit in your custom manager and define it in your `User` model.

It could be like -

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, date_of_birth, password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            date_of_birth=date_of_birth,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, date_of_birth, password):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            password=password,
            date_of_birth=date_of_birth,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=False, unique=True, verbose_name='Email', name='email')
    objects = UserManager()
```

This is quit simple example, you can use `UserManager` as per your requirements.

It is recommenced to refer documentation for more clear understanding  - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/

Comment: As I mentioned, I tried that method when I used the `AbstractBaseUser` approach and it made no difference. I just added the same approach here and confirmed that the same error is being thrown still.