# Python Django: Customize User

Tags: python, django

I only use the Rest_Api from Django 4.1 Python.
Thats my project Setting:

```
mealSheetAI
  setting.py
   mealSheetApi
     admin.py
     models.py
```

models.py

```python
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email =  models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

admin.py

```python
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from .models import User

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'mealSheetApi.User'
```

My Problem is I can't set the User. I got an error like this:

[Manager isn't available; User has been swapped for 'pet.Person'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17873855/manager-isnt-available-user-has-been-swapped-for-pet-person/71360429#71360429)

Comment: What is you issue?
Please elaborate the problem.

Comment: @RahulHindocha I have change the post.