Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'main.User'
I had to recreate User model. I have added custom phone and zip_code fields to the model. But I am encountering Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'main.User' error.
This is my settings.py:
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'main.User'

This is my models.py:
class User(AbstractUser):
    phone = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    zip_code = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    
    class Meta(AbstractUser.Meta):
        swappable = "AUTH_USER_MODEL"


User = get_user_model()

This is my views.py where I am encountering an error:
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
def register(request):
    try:
        first_name = request.data.get('first_name')
        last_name = request.data.get('last_name')
        phone = request.data.get('phone')
        username = request.data.get('username')
        password = request.data.get('password')
        confirm_password = request.data.get('confirm_password')
        if password == confirm_password:
            User.objects.create_user(
                username=username, 
                password=password, 
                first_name=first_name, 
                last_name=last_name,
                phone=phone,
                )
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            login(request, user)
            return Response({'status':True})
        else:
            return Response({'status':False})
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return Response({'status':False})


Try the solution presented at https://stackoverflow.com/a/17874111/10951070
